# Expectation value of the product of two operators

Tags: operator-algebras

Does $\langle A^2B^2\rangle = \langle B^2A^2\rangle$ (i.e. the operators $A$ and $B$ commute) somehow imply

$\langle A^2\rangle = \langle B^2\rangle$? If so, why?

To add some context, my operators are the $x$ and $y$ components of the angular momentum operator. I require the one to imply the other for a proof I am attempting!

Comment: Consider the case where $A$ is any operator such that $\langle A^2 \rangle \neq 0$ and $B = 0$.

Comment: I changed $<A^2>= <B^2>$ to $\langle A^2\rangle = \langle B^2\rangle$, and "A and B" to "$A$ and $B$".  That is standard usage. $\qquad$

Comment: What's the meaning of the angle brackets here?

Comment: @MartinArgerami Means expectation value of. QM definition, integrating between infinity and -infinity.

Comment: Yes, that was obvious from the title. What's the expectation of an operator?

Comment: @MartinArgerami Oh, sorry. I've only encountered them in quantum mechanics, and only seen them applied to operators there. Well, technically there should also be a 'test function', I suppose. Integrate between infinity and -infinity with the operator between the conjugate of the wavefunction and the wavefunction.

Comment: Physicists use angle brackets to mean what they call "expectation value", and as far as I know only physicists say "expectation value" instead of "expected value" or just "expectation". $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no. You can try with $A,B$ numbers (i.e., scalar multiplies of the identity). If $A=1$, $B=2$, then $\langle A^2B^2\rangle = \langle B^2A^2\rangle=4$, while $\langle A^2\rangle=1$, $\langle B^2\rangle = 4$.